# System.TypeLoadException when getting camera permission

Tags: xamarin, permissions, camera

i am trying to start camera and get a photo using xamarin forms app
and asking for the permission as per the following code

```
var st = await Permissions.CheckStatusAsync<Permissions.Camera>();
            if (st.Equals(PermissionStatus.Granted))
            {
                if (!CrossMedia.Current.IsCameraAvailable || !CrossMedia.Current.IsTakePhotoSupported)
                {
                    await DisplayAlert("لا يوجد كاميرا", "جهازك لا يحتوي على كاميرا", "OK");
                    return;
                }
                var file = await CrossMedia.Current.TakePhotoAsync(new StoreCameraMediaOptions { SaveToAlbum = true });
                if (file == null)
                {
                    return;
                }

                pic1.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() =>
                {
                    var stream = file.GetStream();
                    file.Dispose();
                    return stream;

                });
            }
```

but it always gives the following error on pressing the button

> System.TypeLoadException: 'Could not resolve type with token 0100006f from typeref (expected class 'Camera' in assembly '')'

i have tried to clean project and rebuild it and also to update all packages but it dosn't works and keep give the same error

Answer (score 0):

Starting in Android 6.0 (API level 23), it needs runtime permission.

On Xamarin.Forms, you could use Permissions Plugin. https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/PermissionsPlugin

First, add the camera permission in Android Manifest. Your Project.Android> Properties> Android Manifest> Required permissions> Camera. After that, it would generate the user permission in AndroidManifest.xml.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
```

Create a Utils.cs.

```
public static class Utils
{
public static async Task<PermissionStatus> CheckPermissions(Permission permission)
{
    var permissionStatus = await CrossPermissions.Current.CheckPermissionStatusAsync(permission);
    bool request = false;
    if (permissionStatus == PermissionStatus.Denied)
    {
        if (Device.RuntimePlatform == Device.iOS)
        {

            var title = $"{permission} Permission";
            var question = $"To use this plugin the {permission} permission is required. Please go into Settings and turn on {permission} for the app.";
            var positive = "Settings";
            var negative = "Maybe Later";
            var task = Application.Current?.MainPage?.DisplayAlert(title, question, positive, negative);
            if (task == null)
                return permissionStatus;

            var result = await task;
            if (result)
            {
                CrossPermissions.Current.OpenAppSettings();
            }

            return permissionStatus;
        }

        request = true;

    }

    if (request || permissionStatus != PermissionStatus.Granted)
    {
        var newStatus = await CrossPermissions.Current.RequestPermissionsAsync(permission);

        if (!newStatus.ContainsKey(permission))
        {
            return permissionStatus;
        }

        permissionStatus = newStatus[permission];

        if (newStatus[permission] != PermissionStatus.Granted)
        {
            permissionStatus = newStatus[permission];
            var title = $"{permission} Permission";
            var question = $"To use the plugin the {permission} permission is required.";
            var positive = "Settings";
            var negative = "Maybe Later";
            var task = Application.Current?.MainPage?.DisplayAlert(title, question, positive, negative);
            if (task == null)
                return permissionStatus;

            var result = await task;
            if (result)
            {
                CrossPermissions.Current.OpenAppSettings();
            }
            return permissionStatus;
        }
    }

    return permissionStatus;
 }
}
```

In MainActivity.cs, add the code in OnCreate method.

```
Plugin.CurrentActivity.CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
```

OnRequestPermissionsResult is needed in MainActivity.cs.

```
public override void OnRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, string[] permissions, 
[GeneratedEnum] Android.Content.PM.Permission[] grantResults)
{
    PermissionsImplementation.Current.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    base.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
}
```

Usage:

```
private async void _button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{        
    var status = PermissionStatus.Unknown;

    status = await CrossPermissions.Current.CheckPermissionStatusAsync(Permission.Camera);

    if (status != PermissionStatus.Granted)
    {

        status = await Utils.CheckPermissions(Permission.Camera);
    }

}
```